# Problems with $.getJSON in certain browsers

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I have a php file that outputs json encoded text via

```
echo '(' . json_encode( $final ) . ')';
```

And i have a javascript file that fetches that page

```
$.getJSON(file, function(data){
var object = eval(data);
alert(object); //for testing
...
```

When any browser other than firefox 3.5 visits the page that calls .getJSON it alerts `null`

BUT!!! If i take the text that is output by the php file paste it into a new file and load that via .getJSON it works fine. It's only when its output by php that it doesn't work.

The only difference i can see is that the PHP file's content length is 2 more than the other, i can't figure out why.

Thanks

---

**UPDATE**

---

I created a small array to test it with other data and it's working. There's something in my data that's causing the issue. Looking now...

a call to array_merge is the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've narrowed it down to a call to `array_merge` that is corrupting the data somehow.

Answer (score 2):

`data` is not a string, it is a JSON object. Therefore eval will not work on it. Try the following instead:

```
$.getJSON(file, function(data){
alert(data); //for testing
```

Comment: still returning null in all browsers except firefox 3.5

Comment: Try removing the brackets from php. There isn't really any point in having them there.